# Repeat items in RecyclerView

Tags: android

I have a RecyclerView that set a adapter for it.

```
CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(db.getallcategory(),this);
RecyclerView recycler_category = findViewById(R.id.recycler_category);
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager=
            new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
recycler_category.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recycler_category.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
LayoutAnimationController animation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(this, R.anim.layout_animation);
recycler_category.setLayoutAnimation(animation);
categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recycler_category.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
```

I have 6 items in `db.getallcategory()`. but when run app, show 6 items that 2 items is repeat first items

My adpter is

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder>
{
    private Context context;
    private List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList;

///constructor
public CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList, Context context)
{
    this.categoryModelList = categoryModelList;
    this.context=context;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_category, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final CategoryModel categoryModel =  categoryModelList.get(position);
    holder.text_category.setText(categoryModel.getName());

    holder.image_category.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(categoryModel.getImage_url(), "drawable",context. getPackageName()));

    holder.card_category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DbHelper db=new DbHelper(context);

            ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter( db.getallfile(categoryModel.getId()),context);
            Activity main=(Activity) context;
            RecyclerView recycler_item =  main.findViewById(R.id.recycler_item);
              recycler_item .setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
             recycler_item .setAdapter(itemAdapter);
            LayoutAnimationController animation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation);
            recycler_item.setLayoutAnimation(animation);
            itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recycler_item.scheduleLayoutAnimation();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryModelList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView text_category;
    public ImageView image_category;
    public CardView card_category;

    public MyViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        text_category=  view.findViewById(R.id.text_category);
        image_category=  view.findViewById(R.id.image_category);
        card_category=  view.findViewById(R.id.card_category);
     }
}
```

}

Comment: show your adapter pls

Comment: plz see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Why are you binding data again on bind view holder click listener.You should remove the code and bind only releated stuff that will happen on click event.

```
holder.card_category.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DbHelper db=new DbHelper(context);

        ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter( db.getallfile(categoryModel.getId()),context);
        Activity main=(Activity) context;
        RecyclerView recycler_item =  main.findViewById(R.id.recycler_item);
          recycler_item .setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
         recycler_item .setAdapter(itemAdapter);
        LayoutAnimationController animation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(context, R.anim.layout_animation);
        recycler_item.setLayoutAnimation(animation);
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recycler_item.scheduleLayoutAnimation();

    }
});
```

Comment: You should perform action on click like select/de-select or remove the resources from an adapter